# Probability of Event

Tags: probability

So I am working on a probability question and I think I am overthinking it. I did my coding in R btw

Question:
There is an annual rainfall in Seattle that is normally distributed with a mean of $30$ inches and standard deviation of $4$.

What is the probability that it takes more than $6$ years before having a rainfall over $55$ inches?

My attempt:

```
year1 <- pnorm(55, mean = 30, sd=4, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

$(1-year1)^{6}$ but my TA said my answer didn't look right

Any assistance would be helpful

Comment: Is the mean 30 or 40?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For mean of 40 I got approximately $99.22\%$ Please give a reply if you want further help.

Comment: damn! I copied a different code from a different question! the mean is 30

Comment: Is my approach correct? I take the probability of the event, (leading to year 1) then subtract that from 1 and take it to the 6th power (in this case because we want to see how it takes more than 6 years)

Comment: In general yes. But what do you have for $P(X\leq 55)$ if $X\sim \mathcal N(30,4^2)$ ? We need more information what you have done.

Comment: When I use the R code stated above. I get - 2.052263e-10

Comment: @GavinRienne Yes,, I got $2.052263\cdot 10^{-10}$ as well for $P(X\geq 55)$ That means we have to calculate $(1-2.052263\cdot 10^{-10})^6$ which is effectively $1$.

Comment: I didn't finish this response. I had it btw! So I wanted to say thanks for the help!